# How to quickly approximate a value

Tags: approximation, calculator

If you had to approximate the value of $\frac{10^6 - 11}{2^{12}}$ quickly and in your head, how would you do it? (The real value is 244.14)

The way I done it on paper was $\frac{10^6 - 11}{2^{12}} \approx \frac{10^6}{2^{12}} = (\frac{5}{2})^6 = (2+ \frac{1}{2})^6$, and then expanded, ignored the $\binom{6}{6}\frac{1}{2^6}$ and approximated $\frac{6}{16}$ to 0.38, from which I ended up with the value 244.13. However this doesn't seem completely viable if had to be done without writing anything down, especially in a time pressured scenario. So I wonder how to go about finding an approximation method that can be done in my head, but also gives a decent approximation to the true value.

Comment: As a rough approximation, I would make use of $2^{10} = 1024$ is approximately $10^3$ and get $\frac{10^6 - 11}{2^{12}} \approxeq \frac{10^6}{2^{12}} = \frac{10^6}{4 \times 2^{10}} \approxeq \frac{10^6}{4 \times 10^3} = 1/4  \times 10^3 = 250,$ which I would guess (without knowing a more accurate value) to be well within $5\%$ of the true value, which is good enough for a few seconds of thought. If I wanted something to the nearest integer, let alone more accurate, I'd just do the arithmetic. However, the method one uses for such problems varies greatly from problem to problem.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro You might even take $250$ and reduce it a little for the $1024$ rather than $1000$ and for the $-11$, perhaps  by about $2.5\%$ or $6.25$ to get about $243.75$ so close to the actual $244.1379\ldots$

Comment: @Henry The intelligent way to do this reduction is to say that $\frac 1{1+0.024}=1-0.024+0.024^2-0.024^3+\dots$ so you need to subtract $0.024\cdot 250=0.006\cdot 1000=6$ and get $244$ as an underestimate. The next term will be that $6$ times $0.024$, which is $0.144$, so you can get to $244.144$ as an overestimate. Multiplying $0.144$ by $0.024$ is, probably, beyond what a normal person can quickly do in his/her head, so I would stop there.